# iOS devices reload page upon text input

Tags: ios, web, textfield, forum

I have a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
<input type="text" name="name" id="nameid" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Whenever I enter a character into the input field on my Ipod Touch/Ipad or whenever text is in the field and the field obtains focus, the device reloads the page. Hence I cannot enter more than one character. I can also place text in the field with javascript but whenever that field obtains focus, the page is reloaded. I've tried all relevant input field attributes from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-SW1)
 that I have found in "developer.apple.com" archives to no avail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had an on resize event that was getting fired on text entry. I took that out of my javacript and all is well.